# Unterminated quoted string : bin/sh

Tags: bash, makefile, syntax-error, sh

I have the following makefile:-

```
all:
    find | grep -E "\.c\$" | xargs gcc -c -I src -I include -w
    gcc -o main *.o -lm -pthread
```

On running `make` I get the following error:-

```
find | grep -E "\.c\ | xargs gcc -c -I src -I include -w
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried answers to similar questions, but adding a SHEBANG line did not help. Also, I have already escaped the `$` character. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Quoting issues aside (I think `make` is trying to expand the *make* variable `$"` before the shell command ever runs; try `grep -E "\.c\$$"` to make sure a literal `$` is passed to the shell.), you are trying to reimplement what `make` can already do.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I didn't know how to escape $ characters

Comment: btw the command worked well directly on terminal

Comment: `find | grep -E "\.c\$" | xargs gcc ...` can be changed by `find -name '*.c' -exec gcc ... {} +`

Comment: `make` does its own variable expansion before the text is ever passed (*verbatim*) to a shell for execution.

Comment: @chepner, I agree with comment, I just noticed that grep and xargs could be avoided

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Yeah, that was for the OP.

Comment: `you are trying to reimplement what make can already do` What does that mean?

Comment: It means you shouldn't have to run `find` and pipe its output to `xargs` to run `gcc` on multiple files.

Comment: I'm voting down this question, because it gives a bad impression about how to use `make`. Even, if the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524180/2989411) given is correct and proper.

Answer (score 2):

`make` already does most of what you are trying to do. Assuming you aren't expecting `find` to look recursively in subdirectories, all you really need is

```
# Rule for building a c file
.c:
        gcc -c -I src -I include -w -o $@ $<

# Make sure all C files are compiled, then link the resulting object files
all: *.c
        gcc -o main *.o -lm -pthread
```

If you *were* expecting to find C source files in subdirectories, you might want to restructure your project slightly, by adding Makefiles to each subdirectory and calling `make` recursively in those directories.

Comment: As you can see, I already have src and include directories. This is a github project, and I could not understand the makefile. So I was trying to write my own

Comment: And *yes*, I am expecting find to look recursively in subdirectories

Comment: @MeetTaraviya The answer given here is the proper answer. Learn how to use available tools and do not reinvent the wheel. Why you need to change the original Makefile? Doesn't it work? You need to add something new?